# MySQL Replication - Can I create a table on a slave without breaking replication?

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

Using master-slave replication, can I write to a table on the slave that DOES NOT exist on the master and never will, without interfering with replication with out-of-sync errors?

The master and slave both have bin logs enabled.

Will I break the replication doing that?

Comment: Yes, it should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your replication is set in master ---> slave mode, there is no problem in writing to a slave table, even if the table is present in master. It wont affect the replication process. In your case, the only possible cause for a replication failure would be when you create a table in your master, which is already in the slave.

So the answer for your question is your replication won't break if you do this.

[Here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/01/09/how-does-mysql-replication-really-work/) is a good refernce